# logging to file on tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, slf4j

I am using Tomcat as a server. I amb also using

This is my pom file:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.21</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.7</version>
        </dependency>
```

And this is my log4j.properties placed on src/main/sources

```
log4j.rootLogger=debug, stdout, R

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

# Pattern to output the caller's file name and line number.
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n

log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.File=example.log

log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=100KB
# Keep one backup file
log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=1

log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%p %t %c - %m%n
```

And this is how I am using it on my classes:

```
 private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

 //...

 logger.debug("TEST");
```

I am able to see the logger messages on the console output when I run it on Netbeans. I know it is recorded on catalina.out but I am not getting example.log anywhere. Where it is supposed to be created?

I am using tomcat embedded on Netbeans, so the path to it is 
`C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.1\apache-tomcat-8.0.27.0_base` but I can't find `example.log` anywhere. I don't want to check `catalina.out` so this is why I want my own log messages to be stored in `example.log.`

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using Logback in your dependencies, but trying to configure log4j.

If you want to use log4j as your logging backend for SLF4J, then use the [slf4j-log4j12](http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html#swapping) and log4j dependencies instead of logback in your pom.xml.

If you want to use logback as your logging backend, then use [logback's configuration](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html) files rather than one for log4j.

Comment: changed file nome to logback.xml and now it is working ( console output has changed  so I know I amb using my .xml file for formatting the log output ). However, I can't find the .log file. Where it is supposed to be stored? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solved, now it is working fine!

```
<configuration>

    <property name="DEV_HOME" value="c:/logs" />

    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>${DEV_HOME}/safeMO.log</file>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>[%thread] %logger{10} [%file:%line] %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date %level [%thread] %logger{10} [%file:%line] %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="debug">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```